# Improving ugly parameter list on traits

Tags: scala, generics, types, traits

The problem I'm looking at involves defining a trait which has type parameters, where it's type parameters have type parameters where I need to know these types as well. For example, consider the following code:

```scala
trait JoinData[A <: Attributes,
               L <: Entity[A], 
               B <: Keyed
               R <: Document[B],
               O <: Output[A, B]] extends Something[A,L,B,R]{

  def method1(a:A) : String
  def method2(L, R) : O = {
     ...
  } 
  ...
}
```

When the user implements this, the types L and R do dictate what A and B have to be, however I'm not sure if it's possible to remove A and B from my API.

This problem is resulting in pretty ugly APIs, where it's pretty difficult for a user to understand why they are having to specify some of the types, or even what they should be.

Can anyone point me at some ideas of how I might resolve this (if at all possible!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to answer your question without any details about your API and how you use it. Currently it's not even clear why monomorphic

```
trait JoinData extends Something {
  def method1(a: Attributes): String
  def method2(e: Entity, r: Document): Output = {
     ...
  } 
  ...
}
```

is insufficient.

You can try to replace (some of) type parameters with type members:

```
trait Attributes
trait Entity {
  type A <: Attributes
}
trait Keyed
trait Document {
  type B <: Keyed
}
trait Something[L <: Entity, R <: Document]
trait Output[A <: Attributes, B <: Keyed]
trait JoinData[L <: Entity, R <: Document] extends Something[L, R]{
  def method1(a: L#A): String
  def method2(l: L, r: R): Output[L#A, R#B] = ???
}
```

using type projections or

```
trait Attributes
trait Entity
trait Keyed
trait Document
trait Something[L <: Entity, R <: Document]
trait Output[A <: Attributes, B <: Keyed]
trait TC[L <: Entity] {
  type A <: Attributes
}
trait TC1[R <: Document] {
  type B <: Keyed
}

abstract class JoinData[L <: Entity, R <: Document](implicit val tc: TC[L]) extends Something[L, R]{
  def method1(a: tc.A) : String
  def method2(l: L, r: R)(implicit tc1: TC1[R]): Output[tc.A, tc1.B] = ???
}
```

using type classes.

Comment: Apologies for not posting something that made it more obvious why I needed to do this (I've had to abstract away from what I'm doing a lot as it's a bit abstract). This answer is perfect! I had actually tried path dependent types but had been a bit foolish in my implementation by leaving type parameters on the defining traits as well,this answer prompted me to do it properly and has sorted me out. My future users say thank you!